# Doctrine2 entities in multiple namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, doctrine-orm, entity, zend-framework2

I'm developing a web application using Zend Framework 2 which will be made of several modules, and I'd like to put the entity classes in the module to which they belong.

Is it possible to do this using Doctrine2 ORM? By reading the docs, it seems to always expect to have all the entities under at most one namespace, while I'd like to have

- Module1\Entity
- Module2\Entity
- and so on...

How could this be made possible?

Thanks to all!

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. The entity-manager loads several drivers, from each `module.config.php`. Each Module has its own driver and Entities. The manager is the host to all of those, so there will be no problems. Or what exactly is it you're having troubles with understanding?

Comment: Well, I've read the docs, but I'm very new to this kind of programming, I always used plain procedural style before. Could you make me an example of how to do the proper config? I haven't tried anything right now 'cause I'm still looking around to find the best tools for the job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first step to doctrine configuration is within your global configuration file to set up the connection. Personally i do this in two files, the first is `./config/autoload/global.php` and the second one being `./config/autoload/local.php`

This is for one very reason and this is that anything containing `local` doesn't get posted into my git repositories. So my credentials are safe.

**./config/autoload/global.php**

```
return array(
  'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
      'orm_default' => array(
        'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
        'params' => array(
          'host'     => 'localhost',
          'port'     => '3306',
          'dbname'   => 'dbname'
        )
      )
    )
  ),
);
```

**./config/autoload/local.php**

```
return array(
  'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
      'orm_default' => array(
        'params' => array(
          'user'     => 'root',
          'password' => ''
        )
      )
    )
  ),
);
```

The second step would be to create a driver for your entities. This is done on Module Namespace base.

**./modules/ModuleNamespace/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
namespace ModuleNamespace;

return array(
  //... some more configuration

  'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
      __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
      ),
      'orm_default' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
          __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

What's happening there? Well, we extend the doctrine['driver'] array by adding a new driver. The driver has the namespace of our module. For this we also need to define the namespace in our configuration file. The driver defines that all Entities for this driver are within a certain path.

The next step done is that the `orm_defaults` driver gets extended by an assignment defining that all `ModuleNamespace\Entity` classes are loaded from our `ModuleNamespace_driver` configuration.

And ultimately this is done for each single module. So no matter if you're having a `Filemanager\Entity\File` or `PictureDb\Entity\File` classes, both will work and both will get loaded. Modules are - by nature - independant from each other. Though they can have dependencies, or rather work well together, they function on their own. So multiple modules with multiple entities are no problem at all ;)

I hope this makes you understand the topic a little bit. For live working examples i have wrote two blog posts covering the topic.

- [Installing Doctrine 2 for Zend Framework 2](http://samminds.com/2012/07/install-doctrine-2-for-zend-framework-2/)
- [First Steps with Doctrine 2](http://samminds.com/2012/07/a-blog-application-part-1-working-with-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/)

These may also help you out a little bit.

Comment: I'd like to ask you a clarification: you've clearly shown me how to configure the drivers for the various modules and to tell them where to find the entities, but how do I configure the proxies folders? I'd obviously like to have them namespaced too.

Comment: idk what you mean by `proxies folders` :S

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Doctrine2 should generate proxy classes for the actual entity classes in order to perform lazy loading, at least this is what I've seen in the docs. For example, they're spoken of here: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html?highlight=proxies

Comment: Well I'm no expert, but i don't think in ZF2 that's needed. As you can see with the first link i've provided, it works just like that ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **DoctrineORMModule** *Proxies* will be written to */data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy*. I'm not sure if you have to create the folder manually and adapt privileges.

Attention:
For some reason the *ZendSkeletonApplication* ships without namespaces set!
[ZendSkeletonApplication / module / Application / config / module.config.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L2)

You may get this error if you forget to set the **namespace** in each *module.config.php*!
*The class ... was not found in the chain configured namespaces ZfcUser\Entity, \Entity, ZfcUserDoctrineORM\Entity*